# Why does JavaScript Date(0) return 1am GMT+1 Jan 1st 1970?

Tags: javascript, date, epoch, dst, gmt

I am in London (GMT time zone).  We are currently in DST.

In the UK, Daylight Saving Time starts in March and ends in October, so Jan 1 1970 would have been outside DST.

However,

```
epochDate = new Date(0);
console.log(epochDate);
```

returns

> Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Greenwich Mean Time)

I expected

> Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)

Does `Date();` return results in the *current* timezone?!

Comment: Internally Date values are *always* based on UTC (GMT).  The "conversion" to local time happens when the Date is converted to a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript `Date(0)` returns GMT+1 because, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time) (and [timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/uk/london?year=1970)), "the British Standard Time experiment, with Britain remaining on GMT+1 throughout the year… took place between 27 October 1968 and 31 October 1971"